# Trouble with scoring in Java dice game?

Tags: java, logic, nested-loops

For my computer science class, we're making a dice game where you can roll 5 dice up to 3 times each, the goal is to get as many matching dice as possible. The points are calculated with 2^(n-1), where n is the number of dice that match. e.g. if your dice are 2,3,3,4,4, you will get 2^1 + 2^1 points, or 4 points. if all 5 dice match, you get 16 points (2^(5-1)), if you have like 3,3,2,3,2, you get 6 points (it took me  a while to figure out how the scoring works, that's why I'm giving so many examples). So I had no problem with the mechanics of the game, I made it so you can roll the dice 3 times and everything, but I'm really having trouble with tallying up the scores at the end. Here's the code i have so far, for the part where it calculates the score (die1 etc is the value of the roll, e.g. die1 = 3):

```
    int matchCount =0;
    int diceArray[]= {die1,die2,die3,die4,die5};
    System.out.println("Your dice are "+die1+", "+die2+", "+die3+", "+die4+", "+die5);
    for (int i =0;i <diceArray.length;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<diceArray.length;j++){
            if (diceArray[j]==diceArray[i]&&j!=i){
                matchCount +=1;
            }//if 
        }//for j
    }//for i
    matchCount /=2;
    System.out.println("You scored "+Math.pow(2, matchCount-1)+" points!");
```

The code above works, but it doesn't calculate the right score. I think what I need to do is have two `matchCount` variables, so I can handle each pair of matching dice separately, because if it's a 2-dice match I can just do something like `matchCount +=1`, but if it's 3 that match, I would have to do `matchCount +=1` and then `matchCount /= 2`. And then at the end, add those two (I'm using 3,3,2,3,2 as my example when I'm trying to figure this out). I just really don't know how to make this happen.

I think this question is a similar thing, but I don't know what language that is, but it might help anyone trying to help me so here: [Need help on figuring out dice game scoring logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737168/need-help-on-figuring-out-dice-game-scoring-logic)

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate array to count the occurrences of each number rolled.

```
int diceArray[]= {die1,die2,die3,die4,die5};
System.out.println("Your dice are "+die1+", "+die2+", "+die3+", "+die4+", "+die5);
int[] rolls = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0}; //1 - 6 respectively
for (int i: diceArray){
    rolls[i-1] ++;
}
int score = 0;
for(int j: rolls){
    if(j>1){
        score += Math.pow(2,j-1);
    }
}
System.out.println("You scored "+score+" points!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have an `array` / `Hashmap` of length 6 and initialize all elements to 0. On every roll of the dice, increment the corresponding index in the array. Eg. if you roll a 4, increment array[3] by 1. In the end, traverse the array and take those values which are greater than 1. Use those as your `n` values and calculate the final score.

Answer (score 0):

Make matchCount an array, which counts up how many times a number appears:

```
int[] matchCount = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
for (int i=0;i<diceArray.length;i++)
{
    matchCount[diceArray[i]]++;
}

int total = 0;
for (int i=0;i<matchCount.length;i++)
{
    if (matchCount[i]>1)    //Like in examples, ignore matchCounts of 1
        total += Math.pow(2, matchCount[i]-1);
}
```

total will then be the score.

Answer (score 0):

I went a slightly different route by having the score be continuously added to after each iteration. Try this:

```
int matchCount = 0;
double score = 0.0;
int diceArray[]= {die1,die2,die3,die4,die5};
for (int i=0; i<diceArray.length; i++){
    int checkAgainst = diceArray[i];
    for (int j=0; j<diceArray.length; j++){
        if (checkAgainst == diceArray[j]){
            matchCount++;
        }
    }
    if (matchCount > 1){
        score += Math.pow(2,matchCount-2);
    }
    matchCount = 0;
}
System.out.println(score);
```